# Why must I use a const& parameter when defining a functor for STL?

Tags: c++, lambda, set, functor, multiset

```
auto cmp = [](pair<int, int> & left, pair<int, int> & right){if(left > right) return true; else return false;};
multiset<pair<int, int>, decltype(cmp)> mt(cmp);
// If I just compile the two lines above, it will work.
// But if I try to insert some elements as below, I'll get errors.
//mt.insert({0, 3});
//mt.insert({1, 1});
```

However, if I add `const` or remove the `&` for the two parameters of `cmp`, it will work.

Why can't I use a non-`const` reference for `cmp` when I try to insert elements into `mt`?

Comment: What would be the meaning of a comparison that modifies the things being compared? Would it apply to things before or after the modification?

Comment: the value type of a multiset<int, int> is not a pair<int, int>. It's a pair<const int, int>.

Comment: @RichardHodges You confuse with a `multimap`. He is using `multiset<pair<int, int>>` (I dropped the predicate).

Comment: @Leon you're right.

Comment: In which case, the value type really is `const pair<int, int>`, in that you cannot get a non-const reference to the values by any means.

Comment: `{if(left > right) return true;}` and what if `left <= right` ? You don't return anything.

Comment: @O'Neil   done. Thanks.

Comment: @Thomas Or just `return left > right;` ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to cppreference, [cmp must meet the requirements of Compare](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset/multiset).

[Compare](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare)'s reference says:

> As with any BinaryPredicate, evaluation of that expression is not allowed to call non-const member functions of the dereferenced iterators.

In order to prevent comparers to unexpectedly change the stored elements' state, you need to either use a const reference or to take the values by copy.

Comment: but when I just define `mt`, I can give it a function with non-const reference?

Comment: @Thomas: the comparer is not being used in the constructor of the multiset. In short, as soon as the comparer is used for the first time *(during insert)*, the compiler complains.

Comment: So, the comparer used in ctor for STL must be const reference or value by copy? Because I tried to use a non-const reference lambda for std::sort and it works.

Comment: `vector<int> vec{2, 1, 3}; std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](int & a, int & b){return a> b;});` ----- this works.

Comment: @Thomas: it depends on how the algorithm/data structure passes the elements to the lambda. `std::multiset` probably passes the elements as `const&`, while `std::sort` simply dereferences the iterators. Using non-`const` references for non-mutating algorithms is a terrible ideas however, see [this example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/RKMfIhd2rTfMoWLa).

Answer (score 0):

The compiler thinks you could possibly change the parameters you pass to the `cmp` function since you have specified references for the input parameters. However the `insert` statement you have is passing constants which cannot be modified (and the compiler knows this). Hence the mismatch.

If you assign two variables and then pass the variables to your `insert()` call, does it work?

Comment: `int a = 1, b = 2; mt1.insert(pair<int, int>{a, b});` doesn't work.

Comment: The emphasis here is that the key in the set must not be modifiable during the comparison, it has little to do with the arguments of insert.